# Vertex to Fragment shader: pass vec3 or recalculate every fragment?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In my vertex shader I pass through positions in world space for each vertex. I use a uniform to pass the position of the cameras in world coordinates to the fragment shader. I need both of the values there independent of the answer of the question.

now what is better practice: calulate a vec3 cameraToSurface ( world space ) in vertex shader and pass it to the fragment shader and let it be interpolated in that process? 
Or should I just recalculate that vector for each fragment in the fragment shader? which would be a simple ( vec3 a - vec3 b ) operation.

Basically: should I pass a vec3 from vertex to fragment shader or recalulate it there, if it is a simple difference operation?
whats the cost of interpolating a vec3 between vertex and fragment shader?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate in the vertex shader, let the interpolation hardware do its job.

However since the camera location is fixed and is the same for all vertices, I don't see a reason why to calculate in the shader at all. Calculate on the CPU and use a uniform. The relation between camera and vertex in world space is simply the vertex view space position so whatever you're calculating right now, it probably can be simplified.

Comment: this means i have to iterate over all vertices (unmap from buffer and touch each individually? ), calculate the distance from camera to each vertex and pass it as a uniform? i cannot pass a different uniform for each vertex, can i? i don't think i understand what you are suggesting. what i need in my fragment shader is the distance from the fragment to the camera to be clear. plus, i am not in eye space in any stage of my setup, as I light in worldspace (after clipping though. i use shadow mapping ) otherwise i could just use the negative fragment position.

Comment: @molostil: Task of the vertex shader is to transform the vertex into clip space. For this you first transform it into view space by the modelview transform and from view space to clip space by the projection transform. By definition in view space the "camera" is at the origin, so the vertex position in view space (i.e. after applying the modelview transform) is the position relative to camera and all you've to do is calculating the length of this vector by using the GLSL builtin function `length`. The transformation matrices are supplied as `mat4` uniforms.

Comment: @molostil: If you don't transform the vertex to view/eye space yet, it's time to do so. BTW, illumination is easiest performed in view space.

Comment: but if you transform it to clipspace you also use your projection matrix and i do that. but in one single step, so i don't really have the eye space stage in between.

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood your fist answer!! _italic_( calculate in vertex shader, let the interpolation hardware do its job ) is a good answer and all i need. i don't have the eye space at any time because i use modelViewProjectionMatrix and do lighting in world space. i don't see any problem with that and my shader works quite well. if there really is a disadvantage with world lighting please let me know. ( i have heavy computation done in fragment shader for participating media effects, which are facilitated by world space lighting ). cheers and thanks a lot for the input!